# How to deal with JavaScript when fetching http Response in C# using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a C# code (it's a Web Application, that's hosted on IIS) where I use HttpWebRequest to get HttpWebResponse. There I make request to any website & get the response as string, then I analysis the response string. But recently I get the response where JavaScript performs data fetching after page is loaded in browser.

I tried to debug this in firebug & saw that at bottom of response there's a JavaScript function that updates the dom elements after pageload. Is there any way that I could do the same in my C# code. I have searched on net about this found not solution till now.

Following is the code I am using:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie();
            cookie.Name = cook.Name;
            cookie.Value = cook.Value;
            cookie.Domain = cook.Domain;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
            cookieList.Add(cookie);
        }

        string postData = string.Format("username=" + txtUserID.Text + "&password=" + txtPwd.Text + "&url=https://example.com/&game=");
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.example.com/Login/authenticate");
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0";
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        ////set the cookie
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie cook in cookieList)
        {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie();
            cookie.Name = cook.Name;
            cookie.Value = cook.Value;
            cookie.Domain = cook.Domain;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
            req.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
        }

        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");//en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Host = "login.example.com";
        req.Referer = "https://login.example.com/Login/logout";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;";
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        //getting the request stream and posting data
        StreamWriter requestwriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        requestwriter.Write(postData);
        requestwriter.Close();
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.ASCII);
        string responseString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        myStreamReader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: You need something that can function like a browser and actually execute javascript. HttpRequest is not capable of doing this. There are several libraries and toools that capable of doing that (for example: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/). If you don't want to use third party library - you may be able to utilize WebBrowser control for that (though won't recommend).

Comment: Can github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp work in Web Application hosted on IIS?

Comment: There is "offscreen" renderer there, which does not depend on any user interface (such as winforms or wpf). This renderer can work in any type of application, including web application.

Comment: Ok, I have seen the link, is there any code samples for using this library, the code looks to be in winForms mode.

Comment: Here is sample code for offscreen rendering: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example They load page (including running all scripts) then make a screenshot of it, but you can easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @Evk I downloaded code, & tried to run it but it has so many build issues when running it on VS2012 Express, also I could not identify how I would be able to use this code in my Web Application?

Comment: You don't need to build that solution (won't work in VS2012 anyway, it's 2017 year after all), just install cefsharp offscreen nuget package. See here for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35471261/5311735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the easy solution to my need. following is the link that I followed:
[Link to tutorial](http://www.michael-whelan.net/using-phantomjs-with-webdriver/)

Following is the code that'll get the results:

First you'll need to import following:

```
using System.Drawing;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

Now the code:

```
        var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
        var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1360, 728);
        var size = driver.Manage().Window.Size;

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/");
        string url = driver.Url;
        //the driver can now provide you with what you need (it will execute the script)
        //get the source of the page
        var source = driver.PageSource;
        //fully navigate the dom
        var pathElement1 = driver.FindElementByName("username");
        var pathElement2 = driver.FindElementByName("password");
        var pathElement3 = driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='SubmitButton']");

        pathElement1.Clear();
        pathElement1.SendKeys("username");
        pathElement2.Clear();
        pathElement2.SendKeys("password");
        pathElement3.Click();

        //Now get the response after login button click
        source = driver.PageSource;
```